# For a matrix $A$ find the smallest positive $n$ for which $A^n=I$

Tags: matrices, permutations

> Let $A$ be a $8 \times 8$ square matrix with $a_{12} = a_{24} = a_{33} = a_{41} = a_{58} = a_{65} = a_{77} = a_{86} = 1$ and all other entries $0$. Then $A^n=I$ for some $n$; find $n$.

I successfully found that $n=3$ by multiplying the matrix $A$ one by one. I want to ask if there is any alternative method that is easier and less tedious.

Comment: yes u are correct i made a mistake thanks for informing

Answer (score 5):

This is a permutation matrix.

We can represent it by

$$(4, 1, 2)(5, 8, 6).$$

which consists of $3$-cycles. Hence $A^n=I$, for $n$ being multiple of $3$.

Comment: How do we that by looking at the permutation matrix we know that is 3 cycle and find the number in the cycles. Sorry that i am new to the permutation matrix.

Comment: It is a permutation matrix because the only entries different from 0 are 1, and there is one 1 in each row and column. Now, you can read the permutation from the indices of the elements: a_ij=1 sends column j to column i. So 3 and 7 stay in the same place; 2–>1->4->2, and this is a 3-cycle; and the same for the other one.

Comment: so the other will be 8->5->6->8 right

Comment: yup, that is correct.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** This is a permutation matrix $P_{\sigma}$ for the permutation $\sigma = (124)(586)$. Permutation matrices have the convenient properties that $P_{\sigma \tau} = P_{\sigma} P_{\tau}$ and $P_{\textrm{id}} = I$. Thus, $n$ is the minimal positive $n$ such that $\sigma^n = \textrm{id}$, that is, the order of $\sigma$.